# Inspect Operand Stack and Local Variable Array of a JVM Frame using JDB

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, jdb

Is there a way in JDB to inspect the operand stack and local variable array of the current frame?  The `help` command says that there's a `locals` command that can be used to list the local variables but with some classes it says `Local variable information not available.  Compile with -g to generate variable information`.  It makes sense that the variable names might not be available if they weren't included during compile time, but what if I just want to reference local variables by their index in the array?  That seems like it shouldn't require any special compile time configuration.  The `help` command also doesn't seem to have anything that shows the operand stack.  If JDB can't do this, is there another free (preferable command-line) tool that can do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Afaik, it’s the HotspotJVM itself that doesn’t support inspecting local variables when the class file doesn’t have the local variable table. I encountered the issue with all debuggers I’ve ever used. When generating an artificial local variable table, they all suddenly work. See also [Debugging ASM-generated bytecode with JDB (or similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385759/2711488)…