# Debugging a Java application without sources

Tags: java, debugging, bytecode

I have got a builded java aplication and am trying to debug it.

This application is executing via command prompt: `javaw.exe -classpath "lib\.;lib\..;lib\1.jar;lib\2.jar;lib\3.jar;...." smt.smt....smt.Launcher`

I already have a decompiled pseudocode, but I need to **DEBUG** the program.

I tried to import all these libraries into Intellij Idea and use Remote Debugging, but some parts of the code seemed to be broken. Sometimes Idea says *'Source code does not match the bytecode'* or *'There is no executable code at...'*. I think these issues are the result of some kind of obfuscation.

I am wondering, is there a way to debug java application without any sources? Is there any tool that can just attach to javaw.exe and debug it step by step with java-bytecode instructions? Something like debugging a native process, but with java-bytecode instead of asm instructions.

Comment: maybe better ask on another StackExchange site: [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) - quick search result: [Java .class bytecode debugger](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7991)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by decompiled pseudocode, but decompilers like JAD and Fern give actual decompiled code. You could recompile the code and get the same functionality. The things you are going to be missing are formatting, comments, and variable/function names.

All that aside, debugging bytecode is going to be significantly more difficult but it is possible. There are some discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385759/debugging-asm-generated-bytecode-with-jdb-or-similar)  and [here](http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=786) that may help you out. Most debugging projects created to debug bytecode are dead because of the added difficulty with, in most cases, no advantage.